# catch/try block doesn't run in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I got a syntax error running the following snippet of Ruby code.

```
catch(:outer)
  m, n = 1,1
  loop do
    catch(:inner)
      for i in 3 .. 100
        m, n = (m*2), m
        throw :outer if m > 9_999
        throw :inner if m > 5_000
      end         # for-loop
    end          # catch(:inner)
  end # loop
end # catch(:outer)
#=> syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting $end
```

It doesn't like the two `end` statements at the end. What is wrong with it?

Comment: Consider `catch value do ..` syntax instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have a `do` after `catch` that matches the `end`. An `end` must match with `do` or a keyword (such as `class`, `module`, `begin`). The `catch` is a method, not a keyword.

Comment: Yes, that's the culprit. Thanks so much

Answer (score 4):

The correct syntax will be:

```
catch(:outer) do
  m, n = 1,1
  loop do
    catch(:inner) do
      for i in 3 .. 100
        m, n = (m*2), m
        throw :outer if m > 9_999
        throw :inner if m > 5_000
      end         # for-loop
    end          # catch(:inner)
  end # loop
end # catch(:outer)
```

ruby blocks match with do-end pair or {},
catch-end is not a ruby statement like for-end